# Were Canadian politicians targeted by an Indian intelligence covert influence operation?

Tags: government, law-enforcement, canada

Global News reported that [Canadian politicians were targets of Indian intelligence covert influence operation](https://globalnews.ca/news/6823170/canadian-politicians-targeted-indian-intelligence/).

> Indian intelligence agencies attempted to use money and disinformation to “covertly influence” Canadian politicians, according to a highly sensitive government document obtained by Global News.

The document shows that Canadian security officials suspected India’s two main intelligence branches had asked an Indian citizen to sway politicians in this country into supporting Indian government interests.

I am skeptical about this news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article is basically a description of [the Canadian court document](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/fct/doc/2020/2020fc461/2020fc461.html) that it links to. I'm not sure there is any public information to go on aside from this document.

It would seem that whatever the Canadian government knew was based on what the subject himself said in his immigration interviews (which started long after the fact, in 2015) plus whatever may have been reported by Canadians he approached (maybe due to investigations provoked by what he divulged in 2015). It's not clear what Indian intelligence may have known or not known about any of that.